# mysqli_fetch_array() returning Resource ID #4

Tags: php

I'm trying to display an image from a blob in a mysqli database. The javascript that displays it works fine, it's the php thats the issue. For some reason, when getting the blob data, it returns Resource id #4, but the same query just swapped to fetch the title works fine.

Heres the PHP:

```
$image = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT CoverImg FROM `$library` WHERE InternalBarcode = '$barcode'"))[0];
```

I use json_encode to get it to my javascript.

Comment: Please call one command after the other.

Comment: that does not change the outcome

Comment: No, but helps debugging.